# How to use a for loop to loop through a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am currently trying to loop through and print specific values from a list. 
The way that I am trying to do this is like this.

```
for i in range(len(PrintedList)):
     index = i
     elem=PrintedList[i]
     print(elem)
     print ("Product = ", PrintedList [index,1], "price £",PrintedList [index,2])
```

However this returns the error of :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.
```

I am really unsure of what to do to fix the problem.

Comment: Post the output (or a small sample) of `print(PrintedList)`, so we can take a look at the actual structure. We can't guess by looking at code that doesn't work =)

Comment: Is it possible you meant `PrintledList[index][1]` and `PrintedList[index][2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're referencing a nested list, you reference each of the indices in separate brackets.  Try this:

```
for i in range(len(PrintedList)):
    index = i
    elem=PrintedList[i]
    print(elem)
    print ("Product = ", PrintedList [index][1], "price £",PrintedList [index][2])
```

Answer (score 4):

Please do not iteerate using indeces, this is ugly and considered non-pythonic. Instead directly loop over list itself and use tuple-assignment, i.e.:

```
for product, price, *rest in PrintedList:
     print ("Product = ", product, "price £", price)
```

or

```
for elem in PrintedList:
     product, price, *rest = elem
     print ("Product = ", product, "price £", price)
```

`*rest` only required if some sublists contain more than 2 items (price and product)

if you need indeces, use enumerate:

```
for index, (product, price, *rest) in enumerate(PrintedList):
     print (index, "Product = ", product, "price £", price)
```

Comment: Definitely the more pythonic way to do it, I was merely trying to address the specific error in the code.  + 1 for the *rest, I didn't know about that.